# Laravel 5.1 - Store Data in Eloquent: Relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database, laravel-5.1

I folowing [Official Laravel 5.1 User Authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication) to create **User Login** and **User Register** and it is run well.

But now, I add another table, **user_detail** table, which contain another data of user like first/last name, gender, etc. This table has **one to one** relationship with **user** table. And I already defining relationships like **hasOne** and **belongsTo**.

I want to ask, how when I registered a new user, the both **user** and **user_detail** table is filled? Although the user_detail tables just filled in the **'id'** only, because the **user** table and **user_detail** table have same id for primarykey and foreignkey.

For reference here my **routes**:

```
...
// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
...
```

**AuthController**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\UsersDetail;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller {
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Registration & Login Controller
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
      | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
      | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
      |
     */

use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers,
    ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data) {
        return Validator::make($data, [
                    'name' => 'required|max:255',
                    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
                    'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data) {
        return User::create([
                    'name' => $data['name'],
                    'email' => $data['email'],
                    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

    protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard';

}
```

Comment: What is the reason you put that data in `user_detail` instead of  `user`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it.

```
$user = new \User($data)->save();
$user_detail = new \UserDetail($detail_data);
$user->user_detail()->associate($user_detail);
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this would likely go in the `create` method in `AuthController`

Comment: can you explain what **" \ "** means?

Comment: Because I have error on first line **$user = new \User($data)->save**.

The error says **syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)**.

Comment: The backslash is a namespace convention. It may or may not be needed depending on where you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think **@ajameswolf** method is to update data. What I need is to create a data in two table which have relation.

I use this method in my **AuthController**.

```
protected function create(array $data) {

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);


        $user_detail = UsersDetail::create([
            'birthOfDate' => null
        ]);

        $user->save();
        $user_detail->save();

        return $user;
    }
```

Comment: Look at the construct of Laravels model class. It accepts new data as an array. Thus if you want to create an entity you can use my method